# AFNetworking batch POST request over 3g fail

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, batch-processing, 3g, operations

I am using the below code as part of an initial sync and pull to refresh sync code for an app.  When the device is running under 3g the POST calls are timing out and I am receiving an error:

Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."

After looking up the same issues online I added an operation queue and used:

manager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2;

to set maximum concurrent operations below the 3 threshold that seems to be a problem for Apple.  However no matter what number I set the maxOperationCount to the app seems to run 4 operations concurrently and 3 work and the forth times out and fails.  This has the effect of making the sync take forever.

I cant see any questswion related to the maxConcurrentOperationCount not working so it must be something in my code?

I cant see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

---

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];

```
NSMutableArray *operationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *entityDict in entityArray){

    NSDictionary *searchData = @{@"userUUID": [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"uuid"],
                                 @"action":@"SELECTrecordsForUser",
                                 @"tableName": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", entityDict[@"prefix"], entityDict[@"entityName"]],
                                 @"fromDate":entityDict[@"fromDate"],
                                 @"entityName":entityDict[@"entityName"],
                                 @"record":@{@"uuid":entityDict[@"uuid"]}
                                 };


    //Create request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", global_baseURLStringJSON, global_RESTfulFileName] parameters:searchData error:nil];

    //Create operation
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog (@"Success");

        NSArray * responseArray = responseObject;

        //Add record details from server into entity in local database
        [self populateLocalDatabase:entityDict[@"entityName"] withData:responseArray];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        //Download failed add to queue for redownload
        NSLog (@"Failed: %@", error);
        [self addToSyncQueue:entityDict forAction:@"SELECTrecordsForUser"];

    }];


    //Add operation to array
    [operationArray addObject:operation];

}

//Track status of operations
NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:operationArray
                                                           progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {

                                                               NSLog (@"Items in Queue %lu", (unsigned long)manager.operationQueue.operationCount);

                                                               NSLog(@"Finished:%f   Total:%lu", (float)numberOfFinishedOperations, (unsigned long)totalNumberOfOperations);

                                                           } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {

                                                              NSLog (@"all done");

                                                               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: 1 forKey:@"syncComplete"];

                                                           }];

//Add to Operation manager
manager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2;
[manager.operationQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

---

Sample Error from Log

```
2015-07-18 11:58:15.899 crew[1649:444527] Items in Queue 25
2015-07-18 11:58:15.899 crew[1649:444527] Finished:1.000000   Total:25
2015-07-18 11:58:15.900 crew[1649:444527] Success
2015-07-18 11:58:15.967 crew[1649:444527] → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x1701f3f00): MagicalRecord Default Context> on the main thread

2015-07-18 11:58:15.969 crew[1649:444527] Items in Queue 24
2015-07-18 11:58:15.970 crew[1649:444527] Finished:2.000000   Total:25
2015-07-18 11:58:15.971 crew[1649:444527] Updated Entity (null)
2015-07-18 11:58:15.972 crew[1649:444527] Success
2015-07-18 11:58:16.116 crew[1649:444527] → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x1701f3f00): MagicalRecord Default Context> on the main thread

2015-07-18 11:58:20.886 crew[1649:444527] Items in Queue 23
2015-07-18 11:58:20.887 crew[1649:444527] Finished:3.000000   Total:25
2015-07-18 11:58:20.887 crew[1649:444527] Failed: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x1700f0a00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x174441f50 "The network connection was lost.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx.php,, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}
```